# Implementation of handlebars-loader in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, webpacker

In my rails app I try to use handlebars. Some code is from this tutorial (https://medium.com/@jphager2/adding-handlebars-to-a-rails-app-with-webpacker-d246c58e0c38) some from the webpacker docs.

I did

```
yarn add handlebars
yarn add handlebars-loader
```

app/javascript/quote.hbs

```
<blockquote>
  {{quoteText}}
  <small>{{quoteAuthor}}</small>
</blockquote>
```

app/webpacker/packs/application.js

```
...    
const template = require('/app/javascript/quote.hbs');
if (document.readyState === 'ready' || document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  addQuote();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addQuote);
}

function addQuote() {
  var quote = {
    quoteText: "If you want to push, then first pull. If you want to go up, first go down",
    quoteAuthor: "Unknown"
  };

  document.body.innerHTML = template(quote);
}
...
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
...
environment.loaders.append('handlebars', {
  test: /\.hbs$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'handlebars-loader',
    },
  ],
})

console.log('environment.loaders :', environment.loaders);
...
```

When calling a page of the app in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./app/javascript/quote.hbs 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <blockquote>
|   {{quoteText}}
|   <small>{{quoteAuthor}}</small>
```

When I call .bin/webpacker I get the console.log from environment.js which includes

```
environment.loaders : ConfigList(8) [
...
{ key: 'handlebars', value: { test: /\.hbs$/, use: [Array] } }
...
]
```

Why does rails not find the loader?